# How to store a number into an NFC tag?

Tags: arrays, arduino, nfc

I'm Vietnamese, so my English is not good. I have an RFID sensor. I want to store data into a block of the NFC tag.

My project is to add one score for the tag when the tag is read. But I can't insert the data as int type (to add the score). But when inserting data into a block, it requests an array of byte type.

I don't know how to convert an int type into an array byte type. 
This project is on Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Use the lowByte and highByte functions or use a simple bitshift.

```
int asInt = 1234;
byte asByte[2];

asByte[0] = asInt >> 8;
asByte[1] = asInt & 0xFF;
```